# Firebase functions won't see pubsub emulator running locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm trying to run firebase functions with pubsub locally.

Have configured emulators with `firebase init emulators`.

`firebase emulators:start --only pubsub` works properly, I can see log:

```
┌──────────┬────────────────┐
│ Emulator │ Host:Port      │
├──────────┼────────────────┤
│ Pub/Sub  │ localhost:8085 │
└──────────┴────────────────┘
```

pubsub emulator config in firebase.json:

```
"pubsub": {
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 8085
},
```

A pubsub handler function is exported:

```
exports.testPubsub = functions.pubsub.topic("test-pubsub").onPublish(async (message) => {
    console.log(`test event received by pubsub handler: ${message.json}`);
});
```

I run firebase functions with: `firebase serve --only functions`

This line appears in console output:

```
functions[pubsub-testPubsub]: function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running."}}
```

Which means function was found but for some reason firebase cannot connect to pubsub emulator, despite all the configs.

And here is the question:
How to test pubsub and firebase functions on local machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours of struggling I finally managed to make pubsub emulator work.

There is nothing about `firebase serve` in [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) so I guess it's a deprecated command. All I found was `firebase emulators:start`.

I followed instructions in **To set up admin credentials for emulated functions:** section. Created a key and downloaded json, exported variable in terminal and ran `firebase emulators:start`.

That worked and I can see my log in outputs.

Can't tell for sure what was the problem, but looks like you cannot `firebase serve` and get in touch with emulator for some reason. You have to run all the emulators if you want them to work with each other.

Notes:

1. if you are using typescript, don't forget to run `npm run build`
2. projectId option should be enough when you create a topic:

```
const pubsub = new PubSub({
  projectId:  "your-test-project",
});
const topic = pubsub.topic("test-pubsub");
```

Comment: Have you managed to call it throw postman request?