# Firebase functions are not running

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi i am having firebase cloud functions, When i run firebase emulator in  local they are not displaying in emulator.below is my functions code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const DomParser = require('dom-parser')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.storeBooking = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .pubsub.topic("responses")
  .onPublish((message) => {
/// some logic
  });
```

when i run emulator must show function storeBooking, But in emulator it is showing as below

```
Watching "D:\backend-functions\booking" for Cloud Functions...
function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator will show like this:

```
Watching "D:\backend-functions\booking" for Cloud Functions…
function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

Which means function was found but for some reason firebase cannot connect to pubsub emulator, despite all the configs.

As per the [documentation](https://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#unix), you need to set up admin credentials to test your functions to interact with Google APIs or other Firebase APIs via the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

The cloud pubsub requires the setup steps described in this section. This applies whether you're using the Cloud Functions shell or firebase emulators:start.

You can follow the instructions **To set up admin credentials for emulated functions** from [documentation](https://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#unix).

For more information you can check with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766084/firebase-functions-wont-see-pubsub-emulator-running-locally).